# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "angebrannt" und "verbrannt"?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, difference, word-choice

Gibt es eigentlich einen Unterschied zwischen ***angebrannt*** und ***verbrannt*** oder sind sie praktisch identisch?

Comment: Eine Soße kann *angebrannt* sein. Dann ist unten im Topf ein Bodensatz, der durch zu heftiges Erhitzen entstanden ist. *Verbrannt* kann sie nicht sein, weil die Soße als ganzes ja noch Wasser enthält.

Comment: @Janka: Sie kann sehr wohl verbrannt sein, in dem nämlich alles Wasser verdampft ist, der Rest dann aushärtete und schließlich verbrannte. Man kann sie dann nirgends mehr drübergießen.

Comment: Dann ist es keine Soße mehr, sondern reines "Angebranntes". Und fünf Minuten später kommt die Feuerwehr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**An**gebrannt ist, was zu großer Hitze *kürzere* Zeit ausgesetzt war; **ver**brannt ist, was zu großer Hitze *längere* Zeit ausgesetzt war. **Angebrannt** bedeutet so viel wie **teilweise verbrannt**. Alles Verbrannte war zunächst einmal angebrannt; die Phase des Angebranntseins kann allerdings so kurz sein, dass man nichts davon bemerkt. Denke an die vom Blitz getroffene Feldmaus.

**Beispiel**

Wenn du ein Schnitzel in die Pfanne legst und es nicht wendest, wird es unten schwarz. Das ist **an**gebrannt. Wenn es weiterhin unbeachtet in der Pfanne liegt, ist es irgendwann überall schwarz. Das ist **ver**brannt.

Die zugehörigen Verben lauten [**anbrennen**](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/anbrennen) und [**verbrennen**](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/verbrennen).

Dass die Vorsilbe **an** gegenüber **ver** für eine mildere Form steht, gibt es auch in anderen Fällen.

> angerostet / verrostet
>
> angefault / verfault
>
> angegilbt / vergilbt
>
> angeschimmelt / verschimmelt
>
> angeschmutzt / verschmutzt
>
> angestaubt / verstaubt

Comment: Hat meiner Meinung nach aber nichts mit der Zeit zu tun.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Für die genannten Beispiele trifft das zu, aber ich wäre vorsichtig mit einer Verallgemeinerung. Gegenbeispiele wären m.E. *an-/verbieten* , *an-/verlaufen* etc.

Comment: Ich stimme Dir zwar grundsätzlich zu, in der Praxis würde es aber wohl reichen, wenn eine Seite eines Schnitzels zu 50 % schwarz ist, um es als _verbrannt_ zu bezeichnen. Der Unterschied liegt vielleicht mehr im "Grad der Zerstörung"? angebranntes Schnitzel: Stück wegschneiden, essen. verbrannt: wegschmeißen; angerostetes Fahrrad: kann man noch fahren. verrostet: fällt beim Ankucken auseinander.

Comment: Eine Schale Benzin kann verbrannt, aber m.E. nicht angebrannt sein.

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn du ein Feuerzeug unter die Schale hältst, wird sie an einer Stelle schwarz und ist damit angebrannt.

Comment: Es geht nicht um die Schale, sondern um das Benzin. Nimm eine Pfütze, von mir aus. Aus Metall oder Keramik gefertigt wird die Schale vielleicht verrußt sein, aber nicht angebrannt.

Comment: @userunknown: Angebranntes Benzin kenne ich auch nicht, es bleibt eben nichts übrig, wenn Benzin an der Luft verbrennt. Von diesem Spezialfall, bei dem _verbrennen_ so viel heißt wie _verschwinden_, handelt meine Antwort nicht.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Du schriebst aber "Alles Verbrannte war zunächst angebrannt". Also nicht alles. Um als Erklärung zu dienen darf Deine Antwort ja nicht von etwas handeln, was der Leser schon vorab wissen muss, sondern soll ja gerade klären, wo die Abgrenzung liegt,

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass es was mit Zeit zu tuen hat.. Das ist so wie mit "angeschossen" und "erschossen". Da hat es auch nichts mit der Kalibergröße zu tuen, sondern nur damit, wie hoch der Schaden ist (lebendig oder tot).

Comment: Ich denke, "Alles Verbrannte war zunächst einmal angebrannt" ist richtig.. aber wenn du die Hitzequelle verstärkst, kannst du etwas auch in kürzerer Zeit verbrennen, in der gleichen Zeit, in der die kleinere Hitzequelle lediglich ein anbrennen verursacht hatte. Von daher denke ich, dass es nicht direkt mit Zeit zu tuen hat, sondern eher etwas mit dem Grad des Schadens.

Comment: Allerdings.. das Beispiel mit Benzin zeigt, dass auch das nicht richtig ist. Es gibt eben Dinge, die *nicht* zu retten sind, wenn Sie einmal _brannt sind. Das zeigt einmal mehr, dass Zeit keine Rolle spielt.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Und was hat _»tuen«_ mit _»tun«_ zu tun? Auch nicht viel, oder?

Comment: @poll du gibst also zu, dass diese Sache wenig mit Zeit zu tun hat. Rückblickend kann man meinen Rechtschreibfehler auch als Trick deuten, um dich aus der Reserve zu locken.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Mitnichten gebe ich etwas zu, völlig unabhängig von der Zahl deiner Hessenverben. Im Gegensatz zu einem Schuss ist eine Verbrennung ein langsamer Vorgang, bei dem die Zeit eine bedeutende Rolle spielt.